# Enigma rotor settings and the notch

Tags: enigma

According to
https://www.reddit.com/r/cryptography/comments/v0sw2r/enigma_ring_settings_question/

> While the rotor is in the machine, the ring+notch+rotor all rotate in
> sync. While the rotor is pulled out, the ring+notch can be detached
> and rotated to a different offset compared to some canonical
> orientation of the inside rotor wiring.

This makes sense.

The online Engima encoder at https://www.101computing.net/enigma-encoder/ Caesar-shifts the rotor configuration based on the ring settings, but does not to shift the notch. Not Caesar-shifting the notch does not appear to be right (please see the Python code at the bottom of the online encoder page). Would someone explain whether I understand this incorrectly.